# Start Oracle 12c enterprise manager in Windows 7

Tags: oracle

I have installed Oracle 12c in Windows 7. The installation was succesful and the RDBMS and the database that I created are working properly.

Then I tried to access to the enterprise manager via web in `https://localhost:5500/em` as the installer told me to do but it doesn't connect.

If I type netstat I get:

```
TCP [::1]:5500 My-PC:49439 TIME_WAIT
TCP [::1]:5500 My-PC:49440 TIME_WAIT
TCP [::1]:5500 My-PC:49441 TIME_WAIT
TCP [::1]:49442 My-PC:5500 TIME_WAIT
```

I am using a proxy but I disabled it for local locations.

I tried this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/doc.1111/e24473/emctl.htm with no success because I couldn't find emctl file or the services it's talking about. I have 5 Oracle services running instead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I forget the name, but do a search for *.log in your oracle directory, and there should be some "em*.log"  see what is in there.

Comment: what's the output of emctl status dbconsole

Comment: oracle rdbms 12c and cloud control 12c is different

Comment: @Munchi: 12c doesn't have emctl, it uses EM Express

Comment: These questions are the same, but provide more background information: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104130/unable-to-open-connect-to-oracle-12c-enterprise-manager-express  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104288/unable-to-display-page-with-oracle-12c-enterprise-manager-database-express

Comment: @OldProgrammer: would you happen to know the exact location of EM Express its log file. I don't even find mention in the documentation that it should exist... Are you sure you're not confused with the old database control?