# Unable to open/connect to Oracle 12c Enterprise Manager Express

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have a just installed a new single instance installation of Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2.0 on Windows x64) with ASM.  The database itself is working OK (can be accessed locally and remotely via port 1521), however I am unable to open Enterprise Manager Express.  (I have tried different browsers).

The listener is up and seems to be configured for Ent. Mgr. Express, plus I can telnet into the relevant ports (tcp:8080 and tcps:5500), however when connecting via a web browser, no data is returned (verified using Fiddler).

Because ASM is being used, there could be two listeners, however all services are actually exposed via the Grid listener, there is no listener configured against the database home.

Any advice would be appreciated as I am not sure where to look next.

"lsnrctl status", "lsnrctl services" output and listener.ora contents are given below.

Thanks,

Chris

"lsnrctl status" output is as follows:

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 15-JUN-2015 23:07:45

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=cba***.cbailiss.com)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                15-JUN-2015 23:02:00
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 5 min. 47 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\grid\cbailiss\product\12.1.0\grid\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\grid\cbailiss\diag\tnslsnr\cbaz***\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=cbaz***.cbailiss.com)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.0.0.5)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=cbaz***.cbailiss.com)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=C:\APP\ORACLE\admin\orcl\xdb_wallet))(Pre
sentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=cbaz***.cbailiss.com)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "+ASM" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+asm", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

listener.ora contents:

```
listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\grid\cbailiss\product\12.1.0\grid\network\admin\listener.ora
Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_LISTENER = SUBNET

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = cbaz***.cbailiss.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ENABLE_GLOBAL_DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_LISTENER = ON
```

"lsnrctl services" output:

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 16-JUN-2015 00:15
:04

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=cbaz****.ad.cbailiss.com)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "+ASM" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+asm", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:1 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: CBAZ****, pid: 1804>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=cbaz****.cbailiss.com)(PORT=51202))
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: Does your server have multiple network adaptors? Check listener.log at the time you try to connect to the webpage. Does it contain a TNS-12518 error? Is the IP address mentioned in this error the same as the IP address your hostname maps to? Or is it the IP address of one of the other adaptors? Is the problem solved if you disable the other adaptors?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing Oracle 12.2.0.1 on Windows 2016 without ASM and without RAC.

First I found that TCP/IPv6 was on so I turned it off.

Then tried following Oracle Note Number (Doc ID 1608258.1) - 12c EM Express shows Invalid Certificate Error in web browser.

Also didn't work.

I fixed it by old school way ... :)

I discovered that the Windows user Oracle_DBA (that logged on the PC and used to install Oracle 12c) don't have any permissions on the 2 files under the folder "xdb_wallet".

So:

1- I changed the ownership for the folder "xdb_wallet" from whatever it was to Oracle_DBA :

[image]

2- changed the ownership of the 2 files ( ewallet.p12 , cwallet.sso ) under the folder "xdb_wallet" from whatever it was to Oracle_DBA :

[image]

3- I did step 1 again , and checked that ownership changed for the 2 file.

The website   https://hostname:5500/em   worked fine on FireFox , because IE11/Win2016 has funny issues with Flash Player.

I don't know from security point of view what that means (steps 1-3), or what threats might happens due to those changes.

Please advice if you know.